# How to include a WHERE clause only when a field has a value?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables where `A` might have a related record in `B`. If it does, I want a field from B, and if not I just want data from A. I tried something like this:

```
SELECT A.field B.field
FROM A, B
WHERE (A.b_id = B.id OR A.b_id IS NULL)
```

If there's a related record in `B`, give me that field's contents. If not, I probably just want to get `NULL` instead.

Is this possible with MySQL, or do I need to get `A`'s record first, see if `A.b_id` had a value and if so then get the data I want from `B`?

Comment: Sounds like a standard LEFT JOIN to me. Which is (one reason) why you should use standard joins and not this archaic syntax

Comment: @ADyson I appreciate your point, and know that I need to get a better grip on the various available joins. :)

Comment: You might like this blog which does a great job at explaining them: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `left join`:

```
SELECT A.field, B.field
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.b_id = B.id
```

Comment: And a comma wouldn't hurt